# Connect 42" 1080p TV instead of monitor to Mac Mini

Tags: connection, hdmi, vga, tv, mac-mini

I have very certain question coming from very certain conditions. I have a big TV (42 inches, 1920×1080). It has HDMI (more than one) and VGA ports. I tried to connect Windows 8 laptop to it and that worked fine. Now I try to decide will Mac Mini work same way. So, the question is: **can I use my big TV instead of a monitor with Mac Mini?** It will be the only screen connected to the computer.

*upd:* HDMI to Thunderbolt adapter is known requirement.

Comment: hdmi to hdmi will always work, but why mention thunderbolt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can. You will need an adapter to HDMI as you said or a VGA one (strongly recommend HDMI though), and it will work like any other screen.

Something to look out for is try to find a setting on your tv/google for your model to find a 1:1 pixel mapping mode or a computer setting. (I have LG and you have to set the input type to PC with the blue button to enable it and it is poorly documented). If you don't do this you will run in to overscan/underscan issues and it will likely look terrible. If you do get it working the screen should be as clear as any computer monitor.

Comment: Both devices specified provide HDMI. I tried it, and it just worked. I was truly afraid the TV would show me a stretched picture but everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Get a mini Display port to HDMI cable like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003BERYLA)